# How to give true and false condition if my column have text and number

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image]My A column contains texts and numbers

[image: 'DP','SP','KP','4','10']

I want to get data like if my A column contains text then '0', if it is numeric then '8' in the column B. How do I do that?

question2: In the other picture in Column C I am trying to divide A1/B1 but when there is text/numeric - it is giving an error. I want to show that error as 0 and the numeric/numeric(4/8 =0.5) values should be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A5), 8, 0))
```

[image: 0]